# TypeScript error props not assignable to never

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-thunk

Hey kind Internet Strangers!

I'm new to coding and TypeScript and I am here to ask for some help.

I am trying to retrieve an array of objects from *props* to which I'll map into a new object with only the information that I need and return it but I am getting errors :(

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Events = (props: any) => {
  const { organization } = props;
  let result = [
    organization.bookings.bookings.map((booking: any) => ({
      title: booking.title,
      start: booking.time.startTime,
      end: booking.time.endTime,
    })),
  ];
  return result;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  organization: {
    bookings: state.bookings,
  },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Events);
```

I get an error at "Events" at the last line (export statement) with the following message:

> TypeScript error:
> Argument of type '(props: any) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType'.
> Type '(props: any) => any[]' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent'.
> Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key  TS2345

For when I get there, can I set this  component like `useState(<Events />)`?

Comment: What is events here? Provide more code. It seems you are passing something wrong to the component.

Comment: An excessive use of `any` turns typescript back to js.

Answer (score 0):

`connect` is supposed to be used on a React Component. Here `Events` is a function which is returning an array of any so it's not a React Component.

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing `let result :any` . Thanks!